# R Shiny: Combining two Apps

Tags: r, namespaces, shiny

Suppose I have two R Shiny apps that share many objects with the same names. Is there any way to quickly combine them into one app.

For example, if I have App 1:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$x1 = renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(1000))
  })
  output$x2 = renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(1000))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("x1"),
  plotOutput("x2")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and App 2:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$x1 = renderPlot({
    plot(rpois(1000,10))
  })
  output$x2 = renderPlot({
    hist(rpois(1000,10))
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("x1"),
  plotOutput("x2")

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the real apps, there are too many "x1"s and "x2"s to rename one by one. Is there an alternative (like using namespaces) to do combine apps.

Comment: This might help http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: you can use `iframe` also